# Slice selection in MRI

Tags: atomic-physics, radio-frequency, imaging, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Studying MRI, I found that excitation is done by applying B1 (RF) and Gz simultaneously.

But, I think that if those are applied at same time, slice selection cannot be done correctly because Gz will continuously changing the resonance frequency of the area.

If Gz is applied first, and thus resonance frequency of the specific area is fixed, then applying Rf would get more stable result.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Gradient coils have a lot of inductance, so you cannot turn them on instantly. It takes several microseconds to “ramp” a gradient coil to the desired stable amplitude.

So in slice selection we will first start ramping the gradient coil, and as soon as it has reached the desired stable gradient amplitude we will turn on the RF. The RF will be transmitted while the gradient is at the desired stable amplitude. As soon as we are done with the RF then we will ramp the gradient down, which also takes a few microseconds.

So the gradient and the RF are “simultaneous” in the sense that they are on together. But due to limitations from the gradient coil inductance, the gradient coil requires a ramping time before and after the RF.